# how to get a "lightbox" like behaviour in Qt

Tags: qt, lightbox2

I have a Qt project where I'm using QGraphicsView framework, also I have popup windows on the scenes. (QDialogs)

When someone clicks on a certain button a popup window appears, and I'm invoking it with the `.exec()` method instead of `.show()` to make it the active one. Also I want to give it a visual effect like [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) provides for html pages, so it would be obvious for the user too, that the background window won't communicate. Do you know any simple solution to make it work? or is it hard to implement in Qt?
EDIT: I don't know if it's obvious of not, but it's a desktop application, not a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found another way to accomplish what I wanted. Like this:

`QWidget* mytranswidget = new QWidget(mybgwidget);

 mytranswidget->setStyleSheet( "background:transparent; background-color:rgba(0,0,0‌​,95)");

 mytranswidget->setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

 mytranswidget->setGeometry(mybgwidget->rect());

 mytranswidget->show();`

I'm doing it at the beginning of my popup widget's constructor so it's being drawn before draw my popup, so it will be shown in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Just create QFrame over necessary area with customized background and transparency. For animation effect you may use QPropertyAnimation + QGraphicEffects and other stuff from qt animation framework.

Comment: I tried this king of code, but it doesn't really works for me. Did you mean this way? (sorry I'm a bit newbie to Qt)

`QFrame* myframe = new QFrame(mybackgroundwindow);
 QPalette palette(Qt::transparent);
 palette.setColor(QPalette:: ,QColor(119,136,153)); //it's a greyish color
 frame->setPalette(palette);
 frame->setGeometry(mybackgroundwindow->rect());
 frame->show();`

Comment: What exactly does not work? And what visual effect you want to apply?

Comment: Now I found another way to accomplish what I wanted. Like this:  
`QWidget* mytranswidget = new QWidget(mybgwidget);
 mytranswidget->setStyleSheet("background:transparent;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,95)");  
 mytranswidget->setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);  
 mytranswidget->show();`  

I'm doing it at the beginning of my popup widget's constructor so it's being drawn before draw my popup, so it will be shown in the right order.